# $X$ and $Y$ at different scales in total least squares?

Tags: total-least-squares

As [this section of the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares#Algebraic_point_of_view) says, the best (in total least squares sense) matrix $B$ that projects $X$ to $Y$ is given by $$B=-V_{XY}V_{YY}^{-1},$$ where $V_{XY}$ and $V_{YY}$ come from the SVD of the augmented matrix $[X\ \ Y]$.

What if my $X$ and $Y$ are at very different scales? For example, the scale of $X$'s entries is roughly at $0.001$, whereas $Y$'s is at roughly $100$. I think the solution will be biased towards $Y$ at cost of $X$: $E_X$ will be huge (compared with $X$ itself, but tiny compared with $Y$) to minimize the total least squares.

Is this an issue? How may I overcome it?

Comment: I think you may want Scaled Total Least Squares http://www.cs.mcgill.ca/~chris/pub/PaiS02b.pdf .